# UUID as primary key throws an overflow error despite trying to use taggit

Tags: django, uuid, django-taggit

I am trying to use UUID as a primary key on a model and it throws an Overflow error when using redirect.

I looked online for similar problems as I assume it should be quite frequent that people want to do that. I came accross:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/issues/679

So I installed dajngo-taggit and I tried to add the snippet on this link in my code but the problem remains.

Below is my current code using the snippet:

**[models.py]**

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase

class Person(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # ...

class UUIDTaggedItem(GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
    # If you only inherit GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, you need to define
    # a tag field. e.g.
    # tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="uuid_tagged_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")

class Car(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # ...
```

**[urls.py]**

```
# ...    
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("<uuid:pk>/car/<int:id>/", CarDetail.as_view(), name="car_detail"),
    # ...
]
```

And the error I get is:

> OverflowError at
> /en/person/c8c91051-5773-4c69-9587-92b468186db7/car/1/
>
> Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

Would you have any ideas of what I could try to fix it? I have been on this issue for quite some time. Thank you!!

Comment: What is the type of the `car` table's `id` column in the database?

Comment: models.IntegerField(default=1). I even tried to replace <int:id> in the path by "foo" and it still raises the same error.

Comment: Have you run migrations?

Comment: Yes. And nothing had changed.